# Dividing 2 big integers in Java

Tags: java, types, type-conversion

I have 2 big integers that I'm working with.

```
BigInteger one = new BigInteger("184032000000");
BigInteger two = new BigInteger("31536000730"); //Number of milliseconds in a year, Approximately
```

I am trying to convert variable one(which is in millesconds) to years by dividing it by two(Approximate number of milliseconds in a year) but I can't seem to do it. I get the error:
**Operator '/' cannot be applied to 'java.math.BigInteger','java.math.BigInteger'**
 I tried using long, double, BigInteger and BigDecimal in all cases, my IDE complains about some error.

My questions is "Is there a way to calculate one/two?" or once I have one(which is in milliseconds), how do I convert it to years? Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Does the code you posted compile by itself (without any references to division anywhere)?

Comment: You can't assign those numbers directly to a `BigInteger` (or to a "`BigInter`").

Comment: I'm not assigning directly, what you see is how I have it and yes it does compile without any references to division anywhere

Comment: @KwekuBlue - what is the error ?

Comment: @KwekuBlue Well now you appear to be constructing new objects, which is good, but what's a `BigInter`?  Please correct the spelling on `BigInteger`, and please provide your code so far, along with the description of what is wrong (exception stack trace? compiler error? incorrect output).

Comment: Error is: Operator '/' cannot be applied to 'java.math.BigInteger','java.math.BigInteger'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigIntegers are immutable, which means when you do operations on them you need to create new ones. Maybe try this?

```
BigInteger one = new BigInteger("184032000000");
BigInteger two = new BigInteger("31536000730"); //Number of milliseconds in a year, Approximately
BigInteger three = one.divide(two);
```

Comment: Hey buddy! It worked!!. Thanks a bunch and I gave you an up vote haha